# What is the volume generated about the x-axis but this curve?

Tags: integration

$y=-0.1x + 1$
Limits are 0 to 5
When squaring y do we expand it as $a^2 +b^2 +2ab$ and then integrate, or increase the power of the brackets to 3 and divide by 3 and the differential inside the brackets?
Please explain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why settle for one when you can have both?
$$\begin{align}\int_0^5\left(1-\frac x{10}\right)^2dx&=\left.-\frac{10}3\left(1-\frac x{10}\right)^3\right|_0^5=-\frac{10}3\left(\frac18-1\right)=\frac{35}{12}\\
&=\int_0^5\left(1-\frac x5+\frac{x^2}{100}\right)dx=\left.\left(x-\frac{x^2}{10}+\frac{x^3}{300}\right)\right|_0^5=\frac{35}{12}\end{align}$$
Multiply by $\pi$ as desired to get the volume of the solid of revolution.